# Git remote add new ${env} not working as github doesn't eval envs

Tags: bash, git, github, environment-variables

Since git doesn't evaluate my env variables how should I got about this line of code?

```
git remote add original ${original_uri}
```

I've tried to do insteadOf too without success.

```
git config --global url.${original_uri}.insteadOf DUMMY_STR
git remote add new2 DUMMY_STR
```

Comment: If you're using bash as the tag says, you're probably using the wrong syntax. Try `$original_uri`

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I still get `fatal: 'test.github2.com' does not appear to be a git repository`, not doing the replace

Comment: It really doesn't appear to be a git repository. Those would normally end on `.git`; i.e: `https://github.com/Ronkiro/http-cats-of-the-day.git` for https://github.com/Ronkiro/http-cats-of-the-day over HTTPS, `git@github.com:Ronkiro/http-cats-of-the-day.git` over SSH

Comment: If it shows the string, it did replace. The variable might be wrong

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I think you misunderstood. I used `test.github2.com` as a dummy string to be replaced by the real value in `original_uri` which evalues to a real git repo url e.g. `https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`. It still shows the dummy str which I guess shows it didn't do any replacement.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos That syntax is perfectly valid bash. See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: @jor2 You said: "Since git doesn't evaluate my env variables ..." Where exactly are you running this? Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Okay so I determined the issue. The entry in my github config file is incorrect. When I use an env variable in my cmd like above i get the following entry`[url]
 echo = https://github.com/org/repo.insteadOf` and when I copy and paste the string directly into the cmd I get what I expect `[url "https://github.com/org/repo"]
 insteadOf = testurl.com
`

Comment: The issue was very silly when I made `original_uri` all caps it works. and when i turn it back to lowercase it doesn't. anyone make any sense of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I made `original_uri` all caps it worked...

```
git config --global url.${ORIGINAL_URI}.insteadOf DUMMY_STR
```